# print particular columns from matched variable bash

Tags: loops, awk, sed, match

I have a textfile (txtfile1) which contains information such as ID, var1, var2, and var3:

```
 T01012 20 30 40
 T01025 21 22 22
 T01000 90 94 20
 ...
```

I also have another textfile (txtfile2) which contains separate information and will contain the same ID's as in txtfile1:

```
 P02013 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
 S01381 -999 10 -999 -999 11
 T01012 -999 -999 -999 23 12
 ...
```

While looping through the ID's that are in txtfile2, I want to extract the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns in txtfile1. I have tried various awk and sed commands to no avail, and am missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated. The desired output from the example provided would be:

```
 T1012 20 30
```

which would ultimately write to a textfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if sorting is not desirable

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

if you want to drop the last field (40 in the selected record)

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{$NF=""; a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

or

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} $1 in a{print $1,a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
join -j1 -o1.1,2.2,2.3 <(sort txtfile2) <(sort txtfile1)
```

- `-j` specifies on what column to join the files
- `-o` lists the fields to output

`join` needs the input files to be sorted, so process substitution is used to pass them sorted to the command.